# Serialize Object (jpg) to internal storage

Tags: android, serialization, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am trying to download a set of .jpg's from Amazon S3 and store them to the internal storage (so they can't be copied by a malicious user).  I have gotten this far but now I am stuck.  I have found multiple questions that deal with bitmaps or arrays but nothing about storing an image and then accessing it later.  Anyone know where I go from here?

```
String itemName = iconNames.getString(iconNames.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbAdapter.KEY_ICON));
        itemName = itemName + ".jpg";
        GetObjectRequest getObject = new GetObjectRequest(bucket, itemName);

        S3Object icon = mS3Client.getObject(getObject);
        InputStream input = icon.getObjectContent();
```

I have looked here in the dev guide and it gives the following code
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

But this is for storing a string, not an image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy `InputStream` to `OutputStream`. Something like this:

```
InputStream input = icon.getObjectContent();
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Transfer bytes from in to out
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = input.read(buf)) > 0) {
    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
}
input.close();
fos.close();
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks!...now I have to figure out what it is doing haha.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following.

```
Bitmap bitmapPicture = someBitmap
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream fOut = null;
File file = new File(path, "tmp.png");
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```

Comment: Isn't this storing it to External Storage though?

Comment: yes, you're right.  Didn't see that part in your original question.